# How to include a module in a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, include, autoload

A module in my gem is included in a class in another gem, which is extended by a custom class in a Rails app:

My gem:

```
module MyGem
    def my_method
    end
end
AnotherGem.send :include, MyGem
```

Another gem:

```
class AnotherGem
end
```

Class in Rails app:

```
class ClassInRailsApp < AnotherGem
end
```

Running this leads to the following behavior:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.4)
irb(main):004:0> MyGem.method_defined? :my_method
=> true
irb(main):005:0> AnotherGem.method_defined? :my_method
=> true
irb(main):006:0> ClassInRailsApp.method_defined? :my_method
NoMethodError: undefined method `my_method' for ClassInRailsApp:Class
```

How can I make sure my module is included before the class is extended?

**EDIT:**

I tried to directly include `MyGem` in `ClassInRailsApp` and the specified instance method is still not available. Could the issue be related to that?

Comment: Your example code here actually produces `true`, so I'm not sure what your problem is, precisely. This should work, and it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your thinking, you're just calling a method, e.g. @object.my_method.  In reality, you're calling Class level method, e.g. Object.my_method, but have it defined as an instance level method. The correct way to do what you're trying would be Object.new.my_method, however, don't do that.

To call a method like this you'd have to define it as a method on the class. See [this page](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/),  for a better understanding. Specifically the section "A Common Idiom" on how to define Class level methods via a module.